# Настройка Visual Studio 2022 для проекта на C#, добавление ссылок в проект

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой:

установил себе VS 2022, создал проект на C#(на net core5).
хочу добавить ссылку на пространство имен system.windows.forms, чтобы поиграть с формами.

но в VS2022 это делается как-то по другому.

в Solution Explorer нажимаю ПКМ по решению далее добавить(add) и не вижу возможности добавить ссылку.

вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пункта ссылки - нет.

если выбиру другой проект (другой фреймворк) - все как ожидается:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Возможно, конечно, дело в том, что в разных проектах я использую разные компоненты(что видно в центральной части), но честно говоря я ожидал, что есть возможность добавить ссылку на нужный мне FW в любом проекте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7dDu.png

Comment: Это не в студии дело, а в типе проекта, в .NET все это перенесено в раздел "Зависимости", который группирует в себе и ссылки, и пакеты NuGet, и все остальное. Касательно `добавить system.windows.forms` - в .NET тоже это по-другому все устроено, вы не должны добавлять это все вручную, а должны указать в `.csproj`, что это WinForms (`<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`) и в название фреймворка должно быть `-windows` (`net6.0-windows` например), после этого, вам автоматически подтянет все необходимые зависимости в проект (Зависимости - Платформы - Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вот я попробовал добавить зависимости руками(честно говоря тупо добавил указанную вами строчку в *.csproj), но не вышло. Можно чуть больше подробностей об этом? ссылка на документацию была бы лучшим вариантом, я полагаю :) Я попробовал создать новый проек использую не .net core, а .net framework, все получилось без проблем, но очень хотелось бы суметь настроить вот такой проект так, как задумал.

Comment: Ну, документацию.. Можете посмотреть [эту](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0), тут показано как перенести с .NET Framework на .NET5 проект, это хорошо показывает отличия между этими двумя типами проектов. Внимание кстати на `Project file`, там то, что должно быть в .csproj файле. А так, почему вы не сделаете сразу WinForms проект на .net5?

Comment: Потому, что это самый простой путь, чтобы получить то, что мне сейчас нужно, уверен, если не смогу разобраться с таким не сложным вопросом, как подключение библиотек(при том уже установленных) и отступлю... то в будущем буду отступать и перед более значимыми трудностями. Уверен, что это не так сложно, немного настораживает, что настройка делается через XML, а не через мышко-кликательные действия(что было бы логично в самом конце 2021 года и в VS 2022), но то, что это надо все прописывать... требует дополнительного изучения. Спасибо за ссылки :)

Comment: Если вы это делаете лишь для того, чтоб "научиться", то не тем вы занимаетесь, ибо мало кто будет делать консольный проект и потом его переводить в WinForms, это как то... нелогично что ли, ибо есть уже готовый шаблон, который в пару кликов установит все за вас. Ну а настройки, есть, ПКМ по проекту - свойства, там будет [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P65Uc.png), выбираете проект под Windows, галку возде WinForms, все, студия за вас сделает все, что я описывал выше.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! ровно это мне и надо было.